# How to programmatically get the Title for a Local Menu Task?

Tags: 7

I have a long list of menu items so i'll cut it short here:

```
$items['admin/skyview'] = array(
    'title' => 'Skyview Main Page',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'skyview_main_page',
);
$items['admin/skyview/tab1'] = array(
    'title' => 'Skyview',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'weight' => 0,
);
$items['admin/skyview/tab5'] = array(
    'title' => 'Sites',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'weight' => 4,
    'page callback' => 'skyview_sites',
);
```

But my question is how do I programmatically get the title of 'Sites' for tab5? When I use `menu_get_active_title` it returns '`Skyview Main Page`' instead.

I've looked through phpstorm for what options it gives me, but I really don't find anything to get the title of a menu local task, however I noticed this can be done in D8 but can it be done in D7?

Comment: FYI I don’t know if this is testcode or not, but you’ll want to fix those access callbacks.

Comment: What's wrong with them?

Comment: It basically says any user can access this path, the only mitigating access check is the one done against `admin/`. IMO you want to do some sort of custom permission check here.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to finally get the title.

I was using `dpm(menu_get_item());` which listed an array, but I had no idea how to access it. I just had to turn it into a variable to hold that data, then I could access it!

```
$db_site = menu_get_item();
$db_site = $db_site['title'];
```